# Are there diminishing return for crowd control?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Considering that warriors can stun for X seconds with the Earthshaker Hammer skill.

If 5 warriors chain stun a target, will it be stunned by 5*X seconds ? (Considering that each stun is landed right after the previous one ends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Relates to:
>   [Is it possible to stunlock in PvP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98440/is-it-possible-to-stunlock-in-pvp)

It stands to reason that if you apply a condition after one has expired it will be applied again, thus if your timing was right you could keep a target stunned for as long as you had skills which could stun available.

Theoretically if you had a skill with 30s cooldown which stunned for 5 seconds, a team of 6 players could keep a target stunned indefinitely.

Whether the stun duration would change with subsequent applications of stun, I would hazard a guess to say that it wouldn't. That each application would last the correct duration.

Comment: If Twilight Arbor is to be trusted, it is possible to get chain stunned for a while...

Comment: It's knockdown which annoys me. I feel so helpless just laying there for what feels like an eternity! :(

Comment: I'd point out that if you outnumber your enemies 6 to 1 *anyway*, keeping them in stunlock sounds like a particularly inefficient way of taking them down compared to, you know, punching them until they stop moving.

Comment: Especially since anyone with even a modicum of sense will have stun-breaking utility escape skill equipped.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that effects which can stack have the proper description it is safe to say that Stun will not stack. If you look at the various effects you will see "Stacks Duration" or "Stacks Intensity", so where nothing is said about it, it simply does not stack.

It is also quite safe to say that, like foods, the last effect applied should be the one taken into consideration (or maybe the longest one).

Bringing a personal experience about it, yesterday my Charr Warrior got in a fight against four ettins and they stunned him multiple times (lazy evader, I know) and it just lasted for the usual amount of time a single stun should give.

Comment: I think he means chained rather than overlapping.

Comment: @DavidYell - not sure, because he says "5*X seconds", like it works for several boons.

Comment: @Gnoupi he then goes on to say "right after the previous one ends" indicating that there is no overlap.

Comment: @DavidYell - I have to learn to read sentences to the end.

Comment: That's true, he clearly meant chaining and I realize it just now... sorry for that... :)