# Is it possible to stunlock in PvP?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there any profession capable of stunlock in PvP?

How would that work?

*"What do you mean by stunlock? Unable to act or move for 5 seconds? For 10 seconds? Indefinitely?"*  (Question made by @Brant)

What I mean by "stunlock" is to stun someone for an "unfair" period of time, giving you a lot of advantage over the stunned player. Such as [Rogues were capable of in World of Wacraft](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5GHbfo2IFU). I won't fix any minimum time for a "stunlock", I'm basically looking after possible chain stuns that are close to "unfair"

Comment: What do you mean by stunlock? Unable to act or move for 5 seconds? For 10 seconds? Indefinitely?

Comment: @Brant Edited question, is it clearer now ? If not, let me know

Comment: He means to execute such a move sequence such that the other player's character is uncontrollable for a period of time.

Comment: So far, no answer, no vote, no nothing. Weird

Comment: I'd look into `Knockdown` for extended cc, although you would probably need a team of players to make it work. You could knockdown, then immobilise, then stun perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

In this video, the owner discusses the situations in which “stunlocking” is possible in GW2. For the purposes of this discussion, I use the term “stunlock” to mean any control-oriented CC that causes the target to lose the ability to take action – e.g. stuns, knockdowns, knockbacks, fear, etc.

**StunLock "Definition":**

In a nutshell, in order for Player A to chain CC (Crowd Control) Player B, the following things must be true:

Player A must spec for multiple CCs and chain them together
Player B doesn’t have the appropriate immunity (e.g. via Stability for control CCs) or relevant stun breaker available
Note that movement-related conditions such as snares (via cripple or chill) and roots can be removed via condition removal.

**How CC is Balanced:**

ArenaNet balanced CCs in this game with the following design decisions:

- Majority of CCs have a short duration (1-2 seconds)
- The cooldown on CC abilities tend to be significant (15+ seconds)
- The number of CC abilities is limited
- The weapon sets that have multiple CC abilities tend to deal below-average damage
- Players can opt to spec for Stability
- Players can opt to spec for stun breaker(s) and condition removal

**Video Demonstration with Comentaries:**

Hit [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1f_urTbE2f8) for the full video with comentaries

The warrior of this video is running a [“Captain Hammer” Warrior build.](http://taugrim.com/2012/06/21/guide-to-gw2-captain-hammer-warrior/)

Comment: But this doesn't answer whether or not you can stunlock in pvp? :P

Comment: See the video. It is, with the right coordination, it is. It's just not very effective if you don't have a team with you to deal the damage you are missing because you are only doing CC's

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't contain that 'yes/no' or 'yes/no, but' that answers your OP? "Watch the video" isn't really an answer.